# AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I'm writing .Net Core WebAPI, here I'm writing Two HttpGet methods one is to fetch all records irrespective of params, and another one is with param(around 25 params), but I'm getting AmbigousMatchException error.

How i can resolve this ?

[image]

below is the code.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SummaryReportController : Controller
{
    DataProvider dp = new DataProvider();

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public SummaryReportController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetSummaryReport()
    {
        dp.ConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("conAccounting_SQLWeb");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = dp.GetDataSetSProc("uspFreight_SearchFreight");

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        return new JsonResult(dt);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetSummaryReportWithParams(SummaryReport sm)
    {
        dp.ConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("conAccounting_SQLWeb");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlParameter[] paramChk = new SqlParameter[21];
        paramChk[0] = new SqlParameter("@VendIDName", sm.VendID);
        paramChk[1] = new SqlParameter("@BOLNumber", sm.BOLNumber);
        paramChk[2] = new SqlParameter("@BOLWeightFrom", sm.BOLWeightFrom);
        paramChk[3] = new SqlParameter("@BOLWeightTo", sm.BOLWeightTo);
        paramChk[4] = new SqlParameter("@InvoiceAmtFrom", sm.InvoiceAmountFrom);
        paramChk[5] = new SqlParameter("@InvoiceAmtTo", sm.InvoiceAmountTo);
        paramChk[6] = new SqlParameter("@DistanceFrom", sm.DistanceFrom);
        paramChk[7] = new SqlParameter("@DistanceTo", sm.DistanceTo);
        paramChk[8] = new SqlParameter("@InvoiceDateFrom", sm.InvoiceDateFrom);
        paramChk[9] = new SqlParameter("@InvoiceDateTo", sm.InvoiceDateTo);
        paramChk[10] = new SqlParameter("@ShipmentDateFrom", sm.ShipmentDateFrom);
        paramChk[11] = new SqlParameter("@ShipmentDateTo", sm.ShipmentDateTo);
        paramChk[12] = new SqlParameter("@ShipperZip", sm.ShipperZip);
        paramChk[13] = new SqlParameter("@ConsigneeCityState", sm.ConsigneeCityState);
        paramChk[14] = new SqlParameter("@ConsigneeZip", sm.ConsigneeZip);
        paramChk[15] = new SqlParameter("@ConsigneeCode", sm.ConsigneeCode);
        paramChk[16] = new SqlParameter("@ConsigneeName", sm.ConsigneeName);
        paramChk[17] = new SqlParameter("@WhseID", sm.WhseID);
        paramChk[18] = new SqlParameter("@LTLFTL", sm.LTLFTL);
        paramChk[19] = new SqlParameter("@TRSO", sm.TRSO);
        paramChk[20] = new SqlParameter("@FTL", sm.FTL);
        ds = dp.GetDataSetSProcWithProc("uspFreight_SearchFreight", paramChk);

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        return new JsonResult(dt);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change `[Route("api/[controller]")]` to `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`
Then the default route of actions in `SummaryReportController`  will be `api/SummaryReport/{actionname}`.You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) about routing.

For example,the route of `GetSummaryReport` action will be `api/SummaryReport/GetSummaryReport`,the route of `GetSummaryReportWithParams` action will be `api/SummaryReport/GetSummaryReportWithParams...`.

And if you want to get `SummaryReport sm` from query,you can add `[FromQuery]` before it.Here is a working demo:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SummaryReportController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public void GetSummaryReport()
        {

            
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public void GetSummaryReportWithParams([FromQuery]SummaryReport sm)
        {
           
        }

    }
    public class SummaryReport
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add the parameter to the route for the second endpoint `[HttpGet("{sm}")]`